# Why does transition-delay not work on a child element when parent is shown?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

This is probably best illustrated with an example. I have a `parent` and a `child`. The parent is hidden by default unless it has an `in` class. Its child should transition its `background-color` from green to white, after a 3s delay, only once the parent receives the `in` class.

So when the parent is shown, the child's background color is already white. There's no 3 second period of orange, with a transition to white. Can someone explain what's happening here?

```js
$('button.show').on('click', () => {
  $('.parent').addClass('in');
});

$('button.hide').on('click', () => {
  $('.parent').removeClass('in');
});
```

```css
.parent, .child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.parent {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.child {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  transition: background-color 1s linear;
}

.parent:not(.in) {
  display: none;
}

.parent.in .child {
  background-color: white;
  transition-delay: 3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <span>Background should start green, then turn white, but transition isn't happening.</span>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<button type="button" class="show">Show parent</button>
<button type="button" class="hide">Hide parent</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a bit confused with exactly when the settings would occur given the display:none starting condition on the parent.

This snippet takes a slightly different path - using a CSS animation which I found easier to control. The animation is not set up until the parent is displayed so there is no room for confusion on timing.

```js
$('button.show').on('click', () => {
  $('.parent').addClass('in');
});

$('button.hide').on('click', () => {
  $('.parent').removeClass('in');
});
```

```css
.parent,
.child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.parent {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.child {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  animation-name: none;
}

.parent:not(.in) {
  display: none;
}

.parent.in .child {
  animation-name: change;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes change {
  0% {
    background-color: green;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <span>Background should start green, then turn white, but transition isn't happening.</span>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<button type="button" class="show">Show parent</button>
<button type="button" class="hide">Hide parent</button>
```

Comment: Great solution. I try to use transitions when I can, but this animation appears to be the only option without the need for additional classes and JS.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not seeing the transition is because the child is never displayed with the first background color. Starts out as `display:none` inherited from parent then switches to parent display and new color at same time.

You need to first display the parent (and the child by inheritance) and then change the color of the child.

The JS

```
 $('button').on('click', () => {
     $('.parent').addClass('in');
     //Without settimeout this will run same time as first added class
     setTimeout(() => $('.parent').addClass('color'), 0);
 });
```

Then in you're css

```
.parent.in.color .child {
    background-color: white;
    transition-delay: 3s;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying, but my preference is not to add a second class to the parent element strictly to transition the child. In my real world project, the parent gets the class via an operation outside of any code designed to handle the child element. It doesn't feel correct for that code to worry about a child element outside of its purview. Is there a solution that doesn't require a second class to the parent?

Comment: By definition any code to display parent is code to display child... In your real world project is the child displayed when the parent is display none?

You can add the class to the child if you prefer

Comment: I should clarify. My parent element is a page-wide container that uses CSS classes to control which "page" the app is currently displaying. Each page is a child of the parent. So if the parent gets a class of `settings`, the settings page is shown. The code handling these page switches is high-level code, not code contained within a `settings.js` module. So say I want an element somewhere within settings to transition into view when settings is shown, I don't want that high-level code having to add a random class to the page-wide container just to generate that transition in settings.

Comment: Ok that makes sense

Comment: Where does the code (or button) that triggers the page changes sit?

Comment: The buttons and their handling code sit higher than `settings.js`, to continue my example. They'd sit in a file akin to something like `app.js`.